# count number of cells with date in the past

Tags: excel-formula

`=COUNTIFS(AI4:AI34,"=&AV103")`

I have a list that looks something like below, and I need to check if any of the dates have past today.  If they have I need to mark the project AT RISK.

I have tried the above formula where cell reference `AV103` is the date (it has the formula `TODAY()` to determine today's date).  It works if I change `AV103` to a specific date i.e. `23/06/2016` but I need the calculation to happen whenever the spreadsheet is opened and not rely on a manual input of the date.  Any ideas?

```
Complete
Complete
complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
n/a
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
Complete
15/06/2016
Complete
n/a
Check
14/06/2016
01/06/2016
30/06/2016
03/05/2016
25/05/2016
```

Comment: Can I add =COUNTIFS(AI4:AI34,"<23/06/2016") works but I don't want to update the date every time as there are numerous columns which need this calculation

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using =Today() function for AV103

```
=COUNTIFS(AI4:AI34,"<="&AV103)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that but this didn't work... I am just getting 0

Comment: I tried this in another sheet without any formatting and it did work so I am guessing there is some formatting on the cells that is messing this up (I wasn't the original creator of this spreadsheet.

Thank you!  :)